How to determine if a restriction on a class in description logic that uses concrete domains is valid?
I am trying to define the class of $drivers$ in description logic using concrete domains. Drivers need to be older than 16 based on laws, but also not everyone over 16 is a driver. Therefore, using a definition, such as union (examples from literature)
$drivers := Person \cup \geq_{16}(age)$, doesn't really help because this would mean that all people over 16 are drivers. Where $Person$ is the class of all people, $age$ is a role, and $\geq_{16}(age)$ is the concept of all things that have an age >= 16 like $\{x \mid \exists y. age(x,y) \land y>16\}$
I'm pretty sure the proper way to define it puts the concrete domain restriction as a subset of $\neg driver$, enforcing that people not 16 are outside the definition of driver.
$\left(Person\cap \geq_{16}(age) \right)\subseteq \neg driver$
How do I determine if this is valid description logic? Is there a procedure for checking something is a decidable statement in FOL?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community Please clarify which part you're unclear on. Thanks

@SvenVoigt The comment to which you have replied is boilerplate, chosen by someone who reviewed your question, and decided that it didn't quite meet the standards of the site.  I would suggest that you read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/ .

@XanderHenderson I thought it was a bot and thought maybe it was managed by LLM so was hoping for additional clarification. And the question includes all of: context, background, references, definitions, and my work

@SvenVoigt I am not saying that I agree with the person who left that comment (it was left by a person, though it is boilerplate).  I was just directing you towards a standard resource.

Not sure if the question I asked was overly simple. But the process I found is:
If $C_1$ is a class and $C_2$ is a class, then $\neg C_1$ is a class, $C_1 \cup C_2$ is a class, and $C_1 \cap C_2$ is a class. In the context of concrete domains, data ranges such as $\geq_{value}(role)$ are a class as well. Finally, $\subseteq$ is a valid TBox axiom. Therefore, we can simplify over the different steps and get a final valid axiom.
$\left( Person\cap \geq_{16}(age) \right) \subseteq \neg driver$
$Person\cap \geq_{16}(age)$ is a valid class because of the intersection. And $\neg driver$ is a valid class because of negation. We are left with
$C1 \subseteq C2$
Which is a valid axiom in DL.
